# handle exceptions in java

Tags: java, exception

Let's suppose we have a situation where one of the record is missing in the books.txt file. How can We handle such a case, so that the program logs a situation to the console and skips it in further processing?

Another situation, we input a wrong category the program should inform the user about this and allowed him to enter the correct value.

Any suggestion would be warmly welcome.

books.txt

```
[Author]
[Title]
[Category]

[Author]
[Title]
[Category]
'''
```

App.java

```
    import java.util.List;
    
    public class App {
        public static void main(String[] args)  {
            String file = "books.txt";
            Parser parser = new Parser();
            List<Book> books = parser.parse(file);
    
            Stats stats = new Stats();
    
            stats.countBooksPerCategory(books);
            stats.topAuthors(books);
            stats.topAuthorsInCategory(books, "category");
     

   }
}
```

Book.java

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class Book {
    private final String author;
    private final String title;
    private final String category;

    public Book(String author, String title, String category) {
        if( author == null || title == null || category == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o ==null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Book book = (Book) o;
        return author.equals(book.author) && title.equals(book.title) && category.equals(book.category);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(author, title, category);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Books{" +
                "author='" + author + '\'' +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", category='" + category + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Parser.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Parser {
    public List<Book> parse(String pathToFile)  {
        File in = new File(pathToFile);
        List<Book> books = new LinkedList<>();

        String line = "";
        BufferedReader inReader = null ;

        try {
            inReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(in));
            int i = 1;
            String author = "";
            String title = "";
            String category = "";

            while ((line = inReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (i == 1) {
                    author = line.trim();
                } else if (i == 2) {
                    title = line.trim();
                } else if (i == 3) {
                    category = line.trim();
                } else {
                    i = 0; 

                    books.add(new Book(title, author, category));
                }
                i++; 
            }
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return books;
    }

}
```

Stats.java

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Stats {

    public void countBooksPerCategory(List<Book> books) {
        Map<String, Integer> counterBookPerCategory = new HashMap<>();
        for (Book book : books) {
            if(!counterBookPerCategory.containsKey(book.getCategory())){
                counterBookPerCategory.put(book.getCategory(),1);
            }else{
                int counter = counterBookPerCategory.get(book.getCategory())+1;
                counterBookPerCategory.put(book.getCategory(), counter);
            }
    }
        for(String k : counterBookPerCategory.keySet()){
            System.out.println("Number book in category" + k + " is " + counterBookPerCategory.get(k));
        }
    }
    public void topAuthors(List<Book> books) {
        Map<String, Integer> authorStats = new HashMap<>();

        for (Book book : books) {
            int counter = authorStats.getOrDefault(book.getAuthor(), 0) + 1;
            authorStats.put(book.getAuthor(), counter);
        }

        for (String author : authorStats.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(author + " -> " + authorStats.get(author));
        }
    }
    public void topAuthorsInCategory(List<Book> books, String category) {
        Map<String, Integer> authorStats = new HashMap<>();

        for (Book book : books) {
            if (book.getCategory().equals(category)) {
                int counter = authorStats.getOrDefault(book.getAuthor(), 0) + 1;
                authorStats.put(book.getAuthor(), counter);
            }
            for (String author : authorStats.keySet()) {
                System.out.println(author + " -> " + authorStats.get(author));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally you would fix this with if statements before you create your book. Of course, you would have to know what a good / bad category is before you can check anything. You could create an enum for that.

Comment: [Create a custom `Exception`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-new-custom-exception) to alert the console if a book is missing while looping over the file.

Comment: For that to work, your input file must have structure.   You assume the first line is author, second line is title, and third line is category.  There's no way to tell that the first line is actually author.   It could be the category entered by mistake.   Maybe you need to include tags to identify each record, and each fields.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I believe enum is usefull but not in this particuall case. What if we load next file with same data structure and different category?

Comment: Well, it depends of course how the categories are handled. If they are more of a dynamic system then enums don't make sense.